# JAVA - External exe locking when called from launcher

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, output, event-dispatch-thread

I have been trying to use a custom output stream to display the output from an executable on a Jtext area.

The executable is called from a button via

```
        try {
            Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cgminer.exe" + " -o " + Infos.Address + ":" + Infos.Port + " -u " + Infos.User + " -p " + Infos.Password);
            p.waitFor();

            String line;

            BufferedReader error = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));
            while((line = error.readLine()) != null){
                System.out.println(line);
            }
            error.close();

            BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
            while((line=input.readLine()) != null){
                System.out.println(line);
            }

            input.close();

            OutputStream outputStream = p.getOutputStream();
            PrintStream printStream = new PrintStream(outputStream);
            printStream.println();
            printStream.flush();
            printStream.close();
        }
            catch (Exception e) {
                // ...
              }
    }

}
```

and then the output is directed to the jtext with

```
public class CustomOutputStream extends OutputStream {
    private JTextArea textArea;

    public CustomOutputStream(JTextArea textArea) {
        this.textArea = textArea;
    }

    @Override
    public void write(int b) throws IOException {
        textArea.append(String.valueOf((char) b));
        textArea.setCaretPosition(textArea.getDocument().getLength());
    }
}
```

My problem is when I call the first class the button locks and no output makes it to the jtext. It is only when I force close the cgminer that the output appears.

Any help is really appreciated as this has my brain warped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My problem is when I call the first class the button locks and no output makes it to the jtext. It is only when I force close the cgminer that the output appears.

This is a classic symptom of tying up the Swing event thread. When you run a long-running piece of code on the Swing event thread (also known as the **EDT** or **E**vent **D**ispatch **T**hread), you prevent the thread from doing its chores including painting the GUI and interacting with the user, effectively "freezing" the GUI.

The solution is not to comment the `waitFor()` as another suggested, but rather to run it and any other blocking code in backgrounds thread such as a SwingWorker. When you do this, make sure to take care to only update your Swing GUI on the event thread. The SwingWorker has a built-in way to do this via its publish and process methods.

For details on this, please check out [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html)

You will also need to do more threading since some lines of your code are blocking and will prevent lines down stream from running until they unblock, but by then all the important action is done. For instance these block:

```
// this blocks
p.waitFor();

// this blocks both times you use it
while((line = error.readLine()) != null){
  System.out.println(line);
}
```

Comment: Doesn't an external process by definition run in an external, well, process? It should be unnecessary to spawn it in a separate thread, `exec()` should return immediately. (Reading its entire output however should go off the EDT. I also have literally no clue what thread `write()` runs on when you pipe a subprocess' output into a custom `OutputStream`.)

Comment: @millimoose: sorry, you're right of course. The Process itself won't block, but `waitFor()` and the `while (...)` loops will. Correcting... ... and thanks!

Comment: +1 for the update; also consider `ProcessBuilder`; for convenience, the [*initial thread*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html) is available for draining the IO streams, as long as the GUI is updated on the EDT.

Comment: Thank you for all your help. I am still a novice using java and although fun it can be quite a task sometime when I do not know what terms to search for.